# Regex pattern to pass tests

Tags: python, regex

I want to write regex pattern by def function lets name it is_number(string), which check if string is integer from range -49 to 49. Also number should no contain insignificant zeros.

So i want to pass test:

```
        self.assertTrue(is_number("50"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("-50"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("-9"))
        self.assertFalse(is_number("7"))
        self.assertFalse(is_number("-200"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("-21"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("18"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("0"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("49"))
        self.assertFalse(is_number("100"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("-49"))
```

I tried something like, but it doesnt work:

```
def is_number(string):
    pattern = r'[-]?\d[1,4]{1,2}*'
    return re.search(pattern, string)
```

Comment: This is not what you are asking, but why don't you just convert the string to an integer and then make sure the number is in the correct range using comparison operators?

Comment: i just have to use regex

Comment: the first two asserts should be assertFalse if your range is from -49 to +49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
^-?(?:[0-9]|[1-4][0-9])$
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Optional `-`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]` Match a digit 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-4][0-9]` Match a digit 1-4 and a digit 0-9 to match a range 10 - 49
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K7Tmab/1)

If you also want to match 50 and -50 and 7 should not match you could add 50 to the alternation and match digits 0-6, 8 and 9 using

```
^-?(?:[0-689]|[1-4][0-9]|50)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K4aBiC/1)

Comment: matching 50 and -50 as well would change the range of valid numbers though...

Comment: That is correct, only in the question there is `self.assertTrue(is_number("50"))
        self.assertTrue(is_number("-50"))`

Comment: I would still make a case for the test being wrong instead of trying to change what the function accepts in general ;)

Comment: Your pattern pass till self.assertFalse(is_temperature("7"))

Comment: @jptak Not sure what you mean by that? I think it matches all of your requirements.

Comment: the test is wrong... it wants to assertFalse on 7 while 7 is within the specified range. Same with the first two asserts.

Comment: @Cribber I see, so the pattern is correct but the test is wrong.

Comment: I got It pass all test, expect - self.assertFalse(is_temperature("7"). It would work if it would be self.assertTrue(is_temperature("7").

Comment: @jptak Should 50, -50 and 7 match or should they not match? Or else the pattern would be `^-?(?:[0-689]|[1-4][0-9])$`  https://regex101.com/r/3Vom3m/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird 50 and -50 should match, but 7 shouldnt(cus its assertFalse). I didnt made mistake with writing tests - tests are copy-paste tbh to be solved.

Comment: @jptak then all the test will succeed using this pattern `^-?(?:[0-689]|[1-4][0-9]|50)$` https://regex101.com/r/17luaQ/1

Answer (score 1):

The pattern matches either

- double digit numbers with leading 1, 2, 3 or 4  (positive and negative)
- or any single digit number (positive and negative)

Regex:

```
^(-?[1-4]\d|-?\d)$
```

To fulfill the range of 49 to negative 49 your tests should actually look like this:

```
    self.assertFalse(is_number("50"))  #  50 must be assertFalse
    self.assertFalse(is_number("-50"))  #  -50 must be assertFalse
    self.assertTrue(is_number("-9"))
    self.assertTrue(is_number("7"))   #  7 must be assertTrue
    self.assertFalse(is_number("-200"))
    self.assertTrue(is_number("-21"))
    self.assertTrue(is_number("18"))
    self.assertTrue(is_number("0"))
    self.assertTrue(is_number("49"))
    self.assertFalse(is_number("100"))
    self.assertTrue(is_number("-49"))
```

Comment: it doesnt pass 1st assert - it would if assert would be assertFalse

Comment: ""if string is integer from range -49 to 49"". why do you try to assertTrue on 50 and -50 if it is outside your specified range?

Comment: specification of task - have to complete all of them

Comment: then the specification of your task is wrong. 50 and -50 cannot assert to True if your range is from -49 to 49.

Comment: lets say we dont have self.assertTrue(is_number("50")). Regex dont pass at self.assertFalse(is_number("7")). Maybe it should be negation of a whole pattern?

Comment: The three tests with the numbers 50, -50 and 7 are coded "wrong" if your range is supposed to be 49 to negative 49. The rest is logically in line with the given range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern,

```
^[-]?[0-4]?\d$
```

The first digit must be within the four digits 0,1,2,3 and 4 and the last digit can be any.

Comment: this will match with parts of the number as well and not only with the entire number - you will need the symbols  ^ and $ to make sure you catch the entire number

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = r'^-?[0-4]?\d$'
```

Try out this regex pattern

Comment: this won't match single digit numbers like -9